# Starting OpenVPN

Tags: linux, openvpn, kali-linux

Starting to do some penetration testing and I’m using this lab called [Pentestit](https://lab.pentestit.ru). I’m just trying to get connected through the VPN so I can begin, the instructions are [here](https://lab.pentestit.ru/how-to-connect).

The instructions on that page tell you to create 3 files which I did by creating the directory and using nano. It's just the last bit:

```
# chmod +x /opt/pentestit/ovpn.sh
# /opt/pentestit/ovpn.sh
```

It says to execute it I guess and as terminal seems to give no feedback and no error I’m trying to work out if it’s working. Or am I missing something in the instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
ps ax | grep openvpn
```

If you find something like this,

```
9853 pts/11   S      0:00 openvpn --config openvpn/vps/vps.conf
10059 pts/11   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto openvpn
```

Then it is working.

Another possibility is to navigate to `www.whatismyipaddress.com` and see where that site thinks you are. If its answer is `vpn.pentestit.ru`, the site you are contacting in the file `lab.ovpn`, then again you are in business.